# I can't help it

Tags: word-usage

- Mom: John, stop playing video-games!
- John: I can't help it!

Could someone explain what John said?

Comment: Please clarify what you don't understand. It is a normal sentence in English.

Comment: 'help' doesn't seem to fit here.

Comment: It's a reference to John's favorite band, [Bananarama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Can%27t_Help_It).

Comment: @Mitch - It fits fine for me. What do you find amiss?

Comment: @Matt - There is no reason why I have to clarify my question because Brett has already perfectly answered. Why didn't you understand the question?

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand, @AngloSaxon. It is a very simple and easy to understand sentence. Hence my question.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/can%27t_help

Comment: It's not really a "general reference", he's asking about the idiom. If he looked up the definitions of all the words, he'd still be wondering what it was that John was trying to assist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

John is saying that he understands his mother's wishes and that he would like to comply, but he is unable to control himself. Most likely, he is saying not that he cannot stop at that instant, but that he cannot avoid playing regularly.